# How to check if a Chinese character is simplified or traditional in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, python-3.4

I'm wondering is there any method to check a Chinese character is simplified Chinese or traditional Chinese in Python 3?

Comment: http://cjklib.org/0.3/library/cjklib.characterlookup.html seems to hold some promise but I'm not competent to write a useful answer from that.

Comment: related: [What's the complete range for Chinese characters in Unicode?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1366068/4279)

Answer (score 7):

`cjklib` does not support Python 3. In Python 3, you can use [`hanzidentifier`](https://pypi.org/project/hanzidentifier/).

```
import hanzidentifier

print(hanzidentifier.has_chinese('Hello my name is John.'))
》 False

print(hanzidentifier.has_chinese('Country in Simplified: 国家. Country in Traditional: 國家.'))
》 True

print(hanzidentifier.is_simplified('John说：你好！'))
》 True

print(hanzidentifier.is_traditional('John說：你好！'))
》 True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`getCharacterVariants()`](http://cjklib.org/0.3/library/cjklib.characterlookup.html#cjklib.characterlookup.CharacterLookup.getCharacterVariants) in `cjklib` to query the character's simplified (`S`) and traditional (`T`) variants. As described in the [Unihan database documentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr38/#SCTC), you can use this data to determine the classification for a character.