# How can I detect certain Unicode characters in a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, cjk

Given a string in Ruby 1.8.7 (without the awesome Oniguruma regular expression engine that supports Unicode properties with \p{}), I would like to be able to determine if the string contains one or more Chinese, Japanese, or Korean characters; i.e.

```
class String
  def contains_cjk?
    ...
  end
end

>> '日本語'.contains_cjk?
=> true
>> '광고 프로그램'.contains_cjk?
=> true
>> '艾弗森将退出篮坛'.contains_cjk?
=> true
>> 'Watashi ha bakana gaijin desu.'.contains_cjk?
=> false
```

I suspect that this will boil down to seeing if any of the characters in the string are in the [Unihan CJKV Unicode blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summary_of_Unicode_character_assignments#Unihan_CJKV_Blocks), but I figured it was worth asking if anyone knows of an existing solution in Ruby.

Comment: Are you using version 1.9 of Ruby, or just an older version without good Unicode regex support?  If you’re using 1.9, you should have access to (some) Unicode properties, like `\p{InCJKUnifiedIdeographs}` or maybe even `\p{Han}`.

Comment: 1.8.7 without Oniguruma; updated the question.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

(ruby 1.9.2)

```
#encoding: UTF-8
class String
  def contains_cjk?
    !!(self =~ /\p{Han}|\p{Katakana}|\p{Hiragana}|\p{Hangul}/)
  end
end

strings= ['日本', '광고 프로그램', '艾弗森将退出篮坛', 'Watashi ha bakana gaijin desu.']
strings.each{|s| puts s.contains_cjk?}

#true
#true
#true
#false
```

\p{} matches a character’s Unicode script.
 
The following scripts are supported: Arabic, Armenian, Balinese, Bengali, Bopomofo, Braille, Buginese, Buhid, Canadian_Aboriginal, Carian, Cham, Cherokee, Common, Coptic, Cuneiform, Cypriot, Cyrillic, Deseret, Devanagari, Ethiopic, Georgian, Glagolitic, Gothic, Greek, Gujarati, Gurmukhi, Han, Hangul, Hanunoo, Hebrew, Hiragana, Inherited, Kannada, Katakana, Kayah_Li, Kharoshthi, Khmer, Lao, Latin, Lepcha, Limbu, Linear_B, Lycian, Lydian, Malayalam, Mongolian, Myanmar, New_Tai_Lue, Nko, Ogham, Ol_Chiki, Old_Italic, Old_Persian, Oriya, Osmanya, Phags_Pa, Phoenician, Rejang, Runic, Saurashtra, Shavian, Sinhala, Sundanese, Syloti_Nagri, Syriac, Tagalog, Tagbanwa, Tai_Le, Tamil, Telugu, Thaana, Thai, Tibetan, Tifinagh, Ugaritic, Vai, and Yi.

Wow. [Ruby Regexp source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/doc/regexp.rdoc) .

Comment: This definitely works in Ruby 1.9, or Ruby 1.8 with the Oniguruma regex engine. I'm using 1.8.7 without Oniguruma, tragically. :(

Great solution, even though it does not help me in this particular case.

Comment: I had to add '# encoding: UTF-8' to the top of the file to make this work. Otherwise I got a invalid character property name error.

Comment: Makes more sense to do `[p{Han}\p{Katakana}\p{Hiragana}\p{Hangul}]`.

Comment: @tchrist that results in `false, true, false, true`.

Comment: @steenslag Then there’s a bug, because `/a|b|c|d/` cannot get a different answer from what `[abcd]` gets when each one of those a,b,c,d is a single character or something that matches a single character, like `\w` or `\p{Han}`. Best check it out very very carefully.

Comment: The new source link (Ruby 2.0): https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc/regexp.rdoc

Comment: are there groups, as in p{south_asian}, p{middle_eastern} etc ? 
or do i have to use multiple OR's to create them ?

Answer (score 9):

Given my Ruby 1.8.7 constraint, this is the best I could do:

```
class String
  CJKV_RANGES = [
      (0xe2ba80..0xe2bbbf),
      (0xe2bfb0..0xe2bfbf),
      (0xe38080..0xe380bf),
      (0xe38180..0xe383bf),
      (0xe38480..0xe386bf),
      (0xe38780..0xe387bf),
      (0xe38880..0xe38bbf),
      (0xe38c80..0xe38fbf),
      (0xe39080..0xe4b6bf),
      (0xe4b780..0xe4b7bf),
      (0xe4b880..0xe9bfbf),
      (0xea8080..0xea98bf),
      (0xeaa080..0xeaaebf),
      (0xeaaf80..0xefbfbf),
  ]

  def contains_cjkv?
    each_char do |ch|
      return true if CJKV_RANGES.any? {|range| range.member? ch.unpack('H*').first.hex }
    end
    false
  end
end


strings = ['日本', '광고 프로그램', '艾弗森将退出篮坛', 'Watashi ha bakana gaijin desu.']
strings.each {|s| puts s.contains_cjkv? }

#true
#true
#true
#false
```

Pretty hacktacular, but it works. It actually detects a variety of Indic scripts as well, so it should probably really be called contains_asian?

Maybe I should gem this up for other poor I18N hackers stuck with Ruby 1.8.

Comment: I think others may find it helpful.

Comment: I have a project stuck on 1.8, too. This solution didn't work for me, but I adapted a solution from another Stack Overflow thread – see my answer here.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a little gem that packages up the approach in steenslag's answer above:

https://github.com/jpatokal/script_detector

It can also take a stab at differentiating between Japanese, Korean, simplified Chinese and traditional Chinese, although due to the complexities of Han unification it only works reliably with large slabs of text.

Comment: I wonder if it's the most up-to-date library.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 1.8 solution based on [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2728344/6962) and using the API from Josh Glover's solution on this thread:

```
class String
  CJKV_RANGES = [
    (0x4E00..0x9FFF),
    (0x3400..0x4DBF),
    (0x20000..0x2A6DF),
    (0x2A700..0x2B73F),
  ]

  def contains_cjkv?
    unpack("U*").any? { |char|
      CJKV_RANGES.any? { |range| range.member?(char) }
    }
  end
end
```