# Rails validation / Input check Foreign Character Set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

We have a customer that wants to block / detect Non European character sets as Arabian and Chinese. People are now filling in our forms with content like this:

[image]

I have no clue what the best way to detect Non European character sets.

So I am wondering which way to go:

- some kind of jQuery input validation
- Rails validation
- ...

Running:

- ruby 1.9.3p551
- Rails 3.2.19

Kr

Comment: One JS approach is to use regex to check if the input contains non-English chars (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840143/jquery-check-if-special-characters-exists-in-string, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters). Another way is to check the char codes like shown here http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/o842p2p2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after 4 hours of searching I have found this beauty:

```
/\p{Arabic}/u
```

And for multiple Encoding you can use:

```
/\p{Arabic}|\p{Han}/u
```

Tested via http://rubular.com/r/AKFhcpjIbL

Found via http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html

Full validation:

```
validates_format_of :first_name, :last_name, without: /\p{Arabic}/u
```

Interesting read in this context -> [How can I detect CJK characters in a string in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681055/how-can-i-detect-cjk-characters-in-a-string-in-ruby)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a validation on your model that ensures the incoming model attributs is [`#ascii_only?`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/ascii_only%3F)

Comment: I tried this and we also have French characters that we want to allow :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do a rails validation in the model:

> http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_format_of

```
class YourModel< ActiveRecord::Base
 validates_format_of :your_field, without: /[^\u0000-\u007F]+/
end
```

`\u0000-\u007F` is the equivalent to the first 255 characters in UTF-8 or Unicode, which are always the ASCII characters.

Comment: Could you please explain what the without Part is?

Comment: you can see the full explanation here: http://dostmuhammad.com/strip-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string-using-regex-regular-expressions/

Comment: Spoke too soon this also doesn't allow French characters

Comment: So is it possible to enhance this to ISO-8859-1?