# How to match Chinese word in Ruby？

Tags: ruby, regex, encoding, chinese-locale

I want to match Chinese word in a string, but it failed

```
irb(main):016:0> "身高455478".scan(/\p{Han}/)
SyntaxError: (irb):16: invalid character property name {Han}: /\p{Han}/
    from C:/Program Files/Ruby-2.1.0/bin/irb.bat:18:in `<main>'
```

What's wrong with it?

The problem is very strange, is it the character encoding problem?

Comment: its working for me though: `2.1.1 :002 > "身高455478".scan(/\p{Han}/)
 => ["身", "高"]`

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: That would (correctly) change the way the regex matches, but it doesn't explain the error.

Comment: irb(main):016:0> "身高455478".scan(/\p{Han}/)
SyntaxError: (irb):16: invalid character property name {Han}: /\p{Han}/
        from C:/Program Files/Ruby-2.1.0/bin/irb.bat:18:in `<main>'

Comment: possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727804/how-to-determine-if-a-character-is-a-chinese-character

Answer (score 5):

I can reproduce the problem in irb. The difference between my Ruby environment and others who can't reproduce the problem is, my encoding in irb is by default `GBK` which is for Chinese.

This can reproduce the problem:

```
#encoding:GBK
p "身高455478".scan(/\p{Han}/)
```

shows error: `invalid character property name {Han}: /\p{Han}/`

To fix the problem, use the UTF-8 encoding:

```
#encoding:utf-8
p "身高455478".scan(/\p{Han}/)
```

Outputs: `["\u8EAB", "\u9AD8"]`

---

As @Stefan suggests, to set irb to use UTF-8 encoding, start irb using `irb -E UTF-8`.

To encode this one string, use [String#encode](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-encode):

```
'身高455478'.encode('utf-8').scan(/\p{Han}/u)
#=> ["\u8EAB", "\u9AD8"]
```

Comment: I had thought that modern Ruby has UTF-8 by default. That is not the case for irb?

Comment: @sawa I'm in China, I guess irb reads environment from my machine and automatically sets the encoding to `GBK`. To be honest, it bothers me sometimes.

Comment: @Yu Hao  but #encoding:utf-8  doesn't work in irb,how to do in irb?

Comment: Start irb with `-E`, e.g. `irb -E UTF-8`

Comment: Otherwise, set your encodings explicitly: `'身高455478'.encode('UTF-8').scan(/\p{Han}/u)`

Comment: Or, perhaps you can write something to `.irbrc` or something.

Comment: Ruby tries to detect the locale from your environment, so setting a UTF-8 compatible locale like `zh_CN.UTF-8` should work.

Comment: @Stefan，i tried -E UTF-8 and zh_CN.UTF-8,but it doesn't work,can you help me?

Comment: @user3673267 `zh_CN.UTF-8` refers to your system's locale, it's not an option for irb's `-E` switch. Maybe you have to set your terminal's character encoding to UTF-8 as well. Just guessing, I don't have a GBK environment here.